# How to chain oauth2ResourceServer and oauth2Login in Spring Security 5.8

Tags: spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I have a spring web app that needs to authenticate requests that may or may not have an Oauth2 token. If the request doesn't have a Bearer token, it should be redirected to the oauth2 login page. If it does have a Bearer token, the oauth2 jwt decoder should be used.
Is it possible to chain the security filters like this? I tried the following but the chain fails with `Cannot resolve method 'and' in 'HttpSecurity'`

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                                       authorizeRequests.requestMatchers("/")
                                                        .authenticated()
                                                        .requestMatchers("/admin/**")
                                                        .authenticated()
                                                        .requestMatchers("/v1/**")
                                                        .permitAll()
            )
            .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("/admin/**")
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2
                .jwt().decoder(jwtDecoder()))
            .and()
            .oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use lambdas to configure an option, you have no `and()`. It is not neccessary and therefore not supported, see [Goals of the Lambda DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/migration-7/configuration.html#_goals_of_the_lambda_dsl):

> **Goals of the Lambda DSL**
>
> The Lambda DSL was created to accomplish to following goals:
>
> - Automatic indentation makes the configuration more readable.
> - The is no need to chain configuration options using `.and()`
> - The Spring Security DSL has a similar configuration style to other Spring DSLs such as Spring Integration and Spring Cloud Gateway.

Since Spring Security 5.2 you could configure security options with or without using lambdas. With Spring Security 7 you will have to use only lambdas, see [Use the Lambda DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.1/migration-7/configuration.html):

> **Use the Lambda DSL**
>
> The Lambda DSL is present in Spring Security since version 5.2, and it allows HTTP security to be configured using lambdas.
>
> You may have seen this style of configuration in the Spring Security documentation or samples. Let us take a look at how a lambda configuration of HTTP security compares to the previous configuration style.
>
> *Configuration using lambdas*
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class SecurityConfig {
>
>     @Bean
>     public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>         http
>             .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
>                 .requestMatchers("/blog/**").permitAll()
>                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
>             )
>             .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
>                 .loginPage("/login")
>                 .permitAll()
>             )
>             .rememberMe(Customizer.withDefaults());
>
>         return http.build();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> *Equivalent configuration without using lambdas*
>
> ```java
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebSecurity
> public class SecurityConfig {
>
>     @Bean
>     public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>         http
>             .authorizeHttpRequests()
>                 .requestMatchers("/blog/**").permitAll()
>                 .anyRequest().authenticated()
>                 .and()
>             .formLogin()
>                 .loginPage("/login")
>                 .permitAll()
>                 .and()
>             .rememberMe();
>
>         return http.build();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The Lambda DSL is the preferred way to configure Spring Security, the prior configuration style will not be valid in Spring Security 7 where the usage of the Lambda DSL will be required. This has been done mainly for a couple of reasons:
>
> - The previous way it was not clear what object was getting configured without knowing what the return type was. The deeper the nesting the more confusing it became. Even experienced users would think that their configuration was doing one thing when in fact, it was doing something else.
> - Consistency. Many code bases switched between the two styles which caused inconsistencies that made understanding the configuration difficult and often led to misconfigurations.